# I can ping my server IP but I can not find the network adapter

Tags: windows, network-adapter

I have a Windows Server 2016 there, you can see this:

[image]

I can ping the Server's IP, and I can see the `network adapter` icon in the login Page.

But, after I login the Windows Server 2016, I can not find network adapter icon in the bottom, but I can ping the IP of it.

[image]

I can not find any network adapter configuration item in the directory too.

[image: t]

there can not find any network adapter files.

[image]

How to solve this strange issue?

===

I follow a friend's indicate:

`get-NETAdapter -name "*"`, but get no registry error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulty reading your screens, and I would advice for a server to set the
display language to English. It will then be much simpler to search for problems
on Google, as most of the available information is in English.

As regarding the missing Network icon (*not* "Network adapter"), its display is
controlled by
*Settings > Personalization > Taskbar > Turn system icons on or off*.
You will need to toggle to On the "Network" item.

For the problem that you are not seeing the Network Neighborhood, you have a serious
problem with your settings and possibly with the driver of the network adapter.
If the network adapter is functional, and even if it cannot communicate with
any other computer, the list always includes at least the computer itself.
The fact that the list is empty indicates a very serious problem.

I suggest to verify the driver of the network adapter and your settings in
*Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Change adapter settings*.
If you are supposed to have Internet connection, verify that this is so.

Right-click the network adapter and verify in Properties the settings
of "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)".
If you have both IPv4 and IPv6 enabled, disabling IPv6 might help to narrow
down the problem.

Check also the network settings in
*Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center > Advanced sharing settings*.
Ensure at least that Network discovery is enabled.

Comment: see my edited post.

Comment: The computer has no identified network adapter. This is either a driver or hardware problem (there are no other possibilities). Please post the network adapter model and driver details.

Comment: If this is because of driver, the IP can not ping out.

Comment: I cannot comment, since I don't know your network, but I'm not convinced that you are pinging this server. Or perhaps the adapter/driver is only partially broken.